# Common buffer in play framework

Tags: java, synchronization, playframework-2.0, classloader

I need to create a buffer (LinkedList) which is to be shared between a Controller and a Model class. I created this buffer inside a model class

```
public class ServerController {

    private LinkedList<JsonNode> data; /* buffer */
    private static ServerController controller;

    public static ServerController getServerController(){
        return controller;
    }

    private ServerController() {
    }
```

I write into this buffer using a method in another model class and am attempting to read the values from a controller method which services a GET request in order to return the data to the client which  requested for it.

```
    @BodyParser.Of(Json.class)
    public static Result getData() {
        ObjectNode result = play.libs.Json.newObject();
        LinkedList<JsonNode> data = ServerController.getController().getData();
        result.put("value", data.toString());
        return ok(result);
    }
```

The issue is that the buffer that is being written into is not the buffer that is being read by the controller. It appears as if Play is instantiating another instance of the `ServletController` class (even though I have made it singleton). How do I make the buffer shared between the two processes ?

Is the classloader loading 2 different instances in this case ?

Comment: i cant see where the ServerController is actually created (private static ServerController controller is not set). And then you have a ServerController.getServerController() method, but getData calls ServerController.getController() - does this method construct a new ServerController?  try putting some logging in the constructor or in various places to see what's getting called and when.

Answer (score 3):

The play framework is a stateless framework, you should not have a memory between requests in the controller layer.

But a common approach is to use the cache API:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaCache

```
Using this simple API you can store data in the cache:

Cache.set("item.key", frontPageNews);
You can retrieve the data later:

News news = Cache.get("item.key");
```